# Friends, operator keyword and scope resolution

Tags: c++, operator-keyword, friend, scope-resolution

```
namespace GameForge
{
    namespace Core
    {
        class CTribool;
    }
}

GameForge::Core::CTribool operator ! ( const GameForge::Core::CTribool& rkTribool );

namespace GameForge
{
    namespace Core
    {
        class CTribool
        {
            friend CTribool operator ! ( const CTribool& rkTribool );

        private:
            EState m_eState;
        };
    }
}


GameForge::Core::CTribool operator ! ( const GameForge::Core::CTribool& rkTribool )
{
    switch( rkTribool.m_eState )
        {
    // Some stuff...
```

Does not compile because m_eState is not accessible within the last definition. The reason is that the friend declaration occurs in the CTribool namespace and thus declares a different function. So i tried to use scope resolution operator as follow.

```
friend CTribool ::operator ! ( const CTribool& rkTribool );
```

and

```
friend CTribool ::( operator ! ) ( const CTribool& rkTribool );
```

But that doesn't work either because somehow CTribool is not recognized as a valid type.
I suspect that the forward declaration is not enough in this case. Any work around ?

Comment: It's not that `CTribool` is not recognized as a valid type. When you're using a qualified name in a `friend` declaration, you must refer to something that is already declared.

Comment: Is there any way to achieve what i'm trying to do ? I mean there is some kind of circular dependency then ( CTribool operators -> CTribool -> friendship to operators ).

Comment: Don’t use `C` as a prefix for classes, it’s never been appropriate and was based purely on a misunderstanding of the MFC naming conventions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strangely enough, you need to do this:

```
        friend CTribool (::operator !) ( const CTribool& rkTribool );
```

You need to specify that your function is in global scope, but without the parentheses, your `::` would bind with CTribool, as if you were doing this:

```
        friend (CTribool::operator !) ( const CTribool& rkTribool );
```

in which case it would think you were specifying a function without a return type.

Answer (score 1):

You should define your operator in the same namespace as you define the `CTribool` class. It's the right way to do it; it will be found during application by [ADL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup):

```
namespace GameForge
{
    namespace Core
    {
        class CTribool
        {
            friend CTribool operator ! ( const CTribool& rkTribool );

        private:
            EState m_eState;
        };
    }
}



namespace GameForge
{
    namespace Core
    {
        CTribool operator ! ( const GameForge::Core::CTribool& rkTribool )
        {
            switch( rkTribool.m_eState )
                {
                // Some stuff...
                }
        }
    }
}
```